# setting max_old_space_size parameter in SailsJS

Tags: sails.js

I am using sails and frequently got error FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory. Suggestion in stackOverflow is to use like the following: node --max_old_space_size=2000 server.js.

How do I set this in Sails?

Comment: Someone recommends using increase-memory-limit, but it doesn't work at all. Yes, this tool append --max-old-space-size=10240 in all node calls inside my node_modules/.bin/* files, but still the memory limit is not increase.

Comment: In sails, server.js doesn't exist. Instead use app.js ie. node --max_old_space_size=4096 app.js

Comment: Actually, I have found the answer, but I don't know how to close this question. I am using pm2, so instead of node app.js, I start pm2 with what Glen said. Thanks, Glen.

Comment: Your welcome, I will throw it up as an answer below.

Answer (score 3):

To set Node.js heap size when starting your sails app use:

```
# node --max_old_space_size=4096 app.js
```

As mentioned in the comments, the same is true when starting your app using forever or pm2 libraries.

For pm2:

```
# pm2 start app.js --node-args="--max-old-space-size=4096"
```

For forever:

```
# forever start -c "node --max_old_space_size=512" -o out.log -e error.log app.js
```

Answer (score 1):

For the development build you could change "lift" command in package.json

From this line:

```
"lift": "sails lift"
```

To the example below:

```
"lift": "node --max_old_space_size=8000 ./node_modules/.bin/sails lift",
```

And then run "npm run lift" as usual